# Can we use Sentry with NoGMS

Tags: firebase, crash, crashlytics, huawei-mobile-services

We are replacing firebase kits with HMS kits and services. Our App uses Sentry and We want to keep it but we don't know whether it can run with NoGMS devices.
is it possible or not ?

Comment: Do you know which dependencies does Sentry depend on? You can check these running `gradle -q dependencies` for the dependencies tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It can be used on NoGMS devices.For more details please you can visit this [link](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0202367545598970325&fid=0101187876626530001)

Answer (score 0):

Sentry does not depend on GMS. According to its [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/),

> Sentry is cross-platform application monitoring, with a focus on error
> reporting.

There are 87 supported platforms: Android, js, iOS… So you can still use it.

Sentry on [Github](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-android/releases)